# How to eliminate for each loop?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am already using following code to get EXCEL.EXE starting time. (Following code is okey)

```
    For Each prog As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        Label100.Text = prog.StartTime.ToString
    Next
```

But I need more professional code.

So, how to eliminate for each loop?

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of `Process.GetProcessesByName`  and check if it's `Length >= 1`:

```
Dim excelProcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
If excelProcs.Length >= 1 Then
    Label100.Text = excelProcs(0).StartTime.ToString()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
End If
```

or use `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` which is a LINQ method:

```
Dim excelProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").FirstOrDefault()
```

Then you can check if `excelProc IsNot Nothing` before you use it:

```
If excelProc IsNot Nothing Then
    Label100.Text = excelProc.StartTime.ToString()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
End If
```

Comment: @Kramer: you have used `GetProcessesByName` multiple times, look at my edited code which does it only once.

Comment: @Kramer: no, still the same, you're using `GetProcessesByName` multiple times which is unnecessary. Why don't you use my code? Use variables.

Comment: I dont like using variables if unnecessary. What is the bad thing if I use multiple times?

Comment: @Kramer: using variables increases readability and testability of your code. Using the function multiple times means is less readable and less efficient. Why do you want to search all processes in the system with the name excel twice if once is already enough? You have asked for professional code. [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), that's professional code.

Comment: @Kramer: as opposed to DRY the unprofesssional approach is repeating everything which is typically referred to as WET("write everything twice", "we enjoy typing" or "waste everyone's time").

Comment: I have to understand what following code is doing `excelProc = excelProcs(0)`

Comment: @Kramer: actually in this example you don't need the `excelProc` variable. You could store the array in `excelProcs` and then access that. `excelProcs(0)` is just accessing the first process of the `Process()` which can contain multiple. Your loop was working but a little but confusing because you only expect and need one excel process.

Comment: Can I replace `excelProc = excelProcs(0)` with `excelProc = excelProcs.FirstOrDefault`?  What does `0` mean?

Comment: @kramer: all arrays or lists are zero based. That means that you try to acess the first item of the array. No, your code wouldn't compile. You could use what i've shown in my answer if you want to use LINQ's `FirstOrDefault`. I've edited my answer to reduce the first approach a little bit. Look at the documentation of [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) and what it returns, it's not a single process but an array.

Comment: Interesting because following code works:-) `excelProc = excelProcs.FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @Kramer: yes, because that is what i've shown in my answer as second approach. That's a LINQ extension method which returns the first item of a sequence(f.e. a list or array). If it was empty you get the default which is `Nothing` for reference types. Again, `excelProcs` is an array and `FirstOrDefault` is a method that returns the first or nothing.

Comment: Have a nice day (HAND), Thank you very much (TYVM)